# JwPlayer with MPEG DASH

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, mpeg-dash

I am trying to get the jwplayer with mpeg dash support working but am having some trouble with that.

I am encountering the following error when the page loads :

Error loading player: No playable sources found.

The jwplayer player code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");

      playerInstance.setup({
      file: 'http://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/media/car-20120827-manifest.mpd',
      dash: true,
      width: 640,
      height: 360
   });
</script>
```

I will appreciate any feedback to help me fix this problem.

Comment: Do you have at least a Premium JW license? Are the DASH files (jwplayershaka.js and provider.shaka.js) colocated with jwplayer.js?

Comment: Also DASH only works in Chrome or Edge right now.

Comment: Yes they are all in the same directory. I will confirm with Chrome. I thought I did check with Chrome too. And yes, we do have the Premium license.

Comment: Verified with Chrome, same error. If the above jwplayer initialisation script works for any of you, then the problem has to be in my copy of the jwplayer.

Comment: Actually, it's more likely to be a problem with your stream. The JW Player files are just text/javascript, and are unlikely to get mangled unless you've been trying to edit them.

Comment: No what I meant was maybe I copied the files incorrectly. But I verified and that is not the problem. So as you suggested, I have to check the stream. I will update if I get to the bottom of this. Thanks.

Comment: Just an update, since I raised this question yesterday. I finally managed to get the above script working. So the jwplayer is working fine, streaming the  MPEG DASH content. There were multiple problems at my end - a) My license was incorrect, then b) I was serving my index.html file locally without a web server. Had to change that to be served via a web server.  Getting up apache on my MacBook (first time) was what took the most time. And finally I have the clip playing. Thanks again for your feedbacks.

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score -1):

You need a div in there which anchors the location for the player:

```html
<div id="myElement"></div>
```

with your script and the div element mentioned above it plays fine for me using JWPlayer7:

```js
<div id="myElement"></div><script type="text/javascript">var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");playerInstance.setup({file: 'http://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/media/car-20120827-manifest.mpd',dash: true,width: 640,height: 360});</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried playing DASH stream (http://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/media/car-20120827-manifest.mpd) in Chrome Canary browser using online JWPlayer [test player](http://demo.jwplayer.com/stream-tester/) which is provided and hosted by JWPlayer themselves and stream did work for me without any issue.